# Using CAML to Update "Person or Group" field in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, caml

My CAML query not work if it contain any "Person or Group" fields.

Here is my CAML:

```
<Batch OnError="Continue" ListVersion="17" PreCalc="TRUE">
  <Method ID="1" Cmd="New">
  <Field Name="Title">fff</Field>
  <Field Name="Person_x0020_or_x0020_Group">test\administrator</Field>
</Method>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the User ID.

```
<Field Name="Person_x0020_or_x0020_Group">[SharePoint User ID]</Field>
```

Comment: you can get the user ID from the user name by another method.

Comment: @Mhd.Yasseen is correct - SP requires the User ID when inserting/updating Person or Group fields via CAML. You can easily obtain the User ID from the login (e.g. domain\username) by querying the site users.